# systematic failure when trying to execute a system command with Cypress

Tags: cmd, cypress

I'm new to Cypress and Javascript

I'm trying to send system commands through Cypress. I've been through several examples but even the simplest does not work.
it always fails with the following message

```
Information about the failure:
Code: 127

Stderr:
/c/Program: Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: No such file or directory`
```

I'm trying cy.exec('pwd') or 'ls' to see where it is launched from but it does not work.
Is there a particular include I am missing ? some particular configuration ?

**EDIT** :
indeed, I'm not clear about the context I'm trying to use the command in. However, I don't set any path explicitely.

I send requests on a linux server but I also would like to send system commands.

My cypress project is in `/c/Cypress/test_integration/cypress`
I work with a .feature file located in `/c/Cypress/test_integration/cypress/features/System` and my scenario calls a function in a file system.js located in `/c/Cypress/test_integration/cypress/step_definitions/generic`.

```
System_operations.features:
Scenario: [0004] - Restore HBox configuration
    Given I am logging with "Administrator" account from API
    And I store the actual configuration
...
```

Then I my .js file, I want to send a system command

```
system.js:
Given('I store the actual configuration', () => {
    let nb_elem = 0
    
    cy.exec('ls -l')
...
})
```

I did no particular path configuration in VS Code for the use of bash command (I just configured the terminal in bash instead of powershell)

Comment: As the path in your secret command(s) that you are having an issue with, but decided was completely unimportant, try using quotes to protect that clearly visible space character in your error message! Please also based upon the fact that you are not a new member to this site, revisit [ask], paying particular attention to submitting a [mcve] of your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with some help, I managed to call system functions by using tasks.
In my function I call :

```
cy.task('send_system_cmd', 'pwd').then((output) => {
  console.log("output = ", output)
})
```

with a task created as follows:

```
  on('task', {
    send_system_cmd(cmd) {
      console.log("task test command system")

    const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
    const output = execSync(cmd, { encoding: 'utf-8' }); 
    return output
      }
  })
```

this works at least for simple commands, I haven't tried much further for the moment.

**UPDATE for LINUX system commands as the previous method works for WINDOWS**

(sorry, I can't remember where I found this method, it's not my credit. though it fulfills my needs)

This case requires node-ssh

Still using tasks, the function call is done like this

```
cy.task('send_system_cmd', {cmd:"<my_command>", endpoint:<address>,user:<ssh_login>, pwd:<ssh_password>}).then((output) => {
    <process output.stdout or output.stderr>
})
```

with the task being build like this:

```
  // send system command - remote
  on('task', {
    send_system_cmd({cmd, endpoint, user, pwd}) {     
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const { NodeSSH } = require('node-ssh')

        const ssh = new NodeSSH()
        let ssh_output = {}

        ssh.connect({
          host: endpoint,
          username: user,
          password: pwd
        })
        .then(() => {
          if(!ssh.isConnected())
            reject("ssh connection not set")

          //console.log("ssh connection OK, send command")
          ssh.execCommand(cmd).then(function (result) {
            ssh_output["stderr"] = result.stderr
            ssh_output["stdout"] = result.stdout

            resolve(ssh_output)
          });
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    }
  })
```